# Border around list items with space

Tags: c#, css

Hi guys ive got a list of information which are generated from a database, in total I have 3 items in my database, at the moment this code generates the list with each item having a border - The problem at the moment is that the border overlaps , so in the inside of the item list , the border is thicker than the outside.

How can I make it so there is spacing between each item in the list, but they retain their border?

Cheers!

```
<div id="SearchResults">
    <ul class="ListView">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostCode)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupID)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Biography)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResearcherID)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KeySkills)<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)<br />


            </li>
        }

    </ul>

</div>

.ListView{

    list-style:none;
    width:100%;    
}



.ListView li{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:15px;

}
```

Comment: c# or css ?????

Comment: add margin-left: if they are horizontal and margin-top: if they are vertical.

Comment: @zackraiyan im using c# to generate the list and css to style it... i think

Comment: @user2796515 to which css class?

Comment: @Viktor the li class

Comment: @user2796515 absolute treat cheers

Comment: @Viktor Great! I added it as an answer if it was helpful.  Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add margin-left: if they are horizontal and margin-top: if they are vertical.

For example

```
.ListView li{
float:left;
border:1px solid green;
padding:15px;
margin-top: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border from all li and then use the consecutive selector by adding this:

```
.ListView li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid green;
 }
```

Comment: This seems to only create a border when 2 list items meet , theres no border on the items on the outside of the list

Comment: If you want just to add a space replace border-left with any margin

Comment: Yeah did the trick, thanks for letting me know about the consec selector, will keep it mind for another time